# Timber footer returns svg?

Tags: wordpress, timber

I actually build a site with timber, below is my composer json :

```
{
  ...,
  "autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    }
 },
 "require": {
    "timber/timber": "1.18",
    "hellonico/timber-dump-extension": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0"
 },
 "require-dev": {
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.3"
 },
 "config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
      "composer/installers": true
    }
 }
```

}

my footer template : `{{function("wp_footer")}}</body></html>`

Oddly, this snippet, doesn't outputs registered scripts but some svg tags that I don't know where they come from (image below)[footer output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL9U0.png).

here how i register my script :
 `wp_register_script('myjs', APP_DIR_URI .'/dist/js/myjs.js', ['jQuery'], "1.0.0", true); wp_enqueue_script('prono');`

Could you please explain me why have this issue, is this related to the version of timber or something else ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That comes with a new WordPress [block themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/block-theme-overview/) and specifically `theme.json` file. You may find more about this file and how to use it [here](https://mkaz.blog/wordpress/using-theme-json-in-a-classic-theme/)

File not just renders svg-filters but creates inline global styles on every page. If you wish to "disable" it (you cannot disable it but you may override such behavior with desired) you may create `theme.json` file at the root of your theme with following content

```json
{
    "version": 2,
    "settings": {
        "color": {
            "duotone": null,
            "palette": null,
            "gradients": null
        },
        "typography": {
            "fontSizes": null
        }
    },
    "styles": null,
    "variables": null,
    "presets": null
}
```